# Notebook with Ryzen freezes when booting

Tags: boot, hp, freeze, amd-ryzen

I installed Ubuntu on a new [HP Elitebook 745 g5 with an AMD Ryzen 7 2700U](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-elitebook-745-g5-notebook-pc/18819802/document/c05997454#AbT3). I used Ubuntu 18.04 (5.0.0-31-generic) and it always froze during boot.

I install edNvidia drivers, and now it boots once out of 5-7 tries. WaylandEnable=false did not help.

In case it boots OK, it works as needed but ... To boot successfully I waste many time.

How may I troubleshoot this?

Comment: @K7AAY thanx, done

Comment: For troubleshooting purposes only, would you mind making a LiveUSB with 19.10 and test with that LiveUSB?

Comment: Have you applied the latest BIOS/firmware updates from the vendor?